# News digest generates wrong link on titles

Tags: sharepoint-online

When sending a news digest, you can select the newsposts to include. After sending the e-mail, the user would get an overview of the newsposts whereas every title of every newspost referred to the newpost itself. Since a couple of days, all links seem to refer to the overviewpage itself instead of the newsposts. Anyone experiencing the same issue ? Care to test to confirm this (same) error ?

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean overviewpage?

This is my test result,if possible, please provide more information such as screenshoot:

[image]